# What does {:?} mean in a Rust format string?

Tags: arrays, rust

I found out that `{:?}` prints an entire array in Rust. I want to know what is it called and how exactly it works. Is it only limited to printing arrays or could it also be used elsewhere for other purposes?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is explained (along with the rest of the formatting syntax) in the [`std::fmt`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) documentation.

`{...}` surrounds all formatting directives.  `:` separates the name or ordinal of the thing being formatted (which in this case is *omitted*, and thus means "the next thing") from the formatting options.  The `?` is a formatting option that triggers the use of the `std::fmt::Debug` implementation of the thing being formatted, as opposed to the default `Display` trait, or one of the other traits (like `UpperHex` or `Octal`).

Thus, `{:?}` formats the "next" value passed to a formatting macro, and supports anything that implements `Debug`.

Answer (score 22):

The [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait is one of the most commonly used in Rust.
It allows you to format the output in a programmer-facing, debugging context. The way you typically use it is like this:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let s = format!("{:?}", v);
```

Also, as of Rust 1.58 you can Debug-format a variable by putting it right after the opening curly bracket, like this:

```
let s = format!("{v:?}");
```

If you want to Debug-format a custom type, such as a struct, you can simply use `derive` like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}
```