# What is the symbol : used in the Debug placeholder {:?}?

Tags: rust

With macros such as `format!`, `print!` and `println!`, we can use the following where `{:?}` is a placeholder for the `Debug` trait `?`:

```
let array = [7; 3];
println!("{:?}", array);
```

This outputs `[7, 7, 7]`.

I am focusing on the `:` — what is it? Is it used in any other context besides formatting?

Comment: What "other contexts" are you referring to that use `:?`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-parameters

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, this question is a duplicate of: [What does {:?} mean in a Rust format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157335/what-does-mean-in-a-rust-format-string)

Comment: This question is specifically about ```:```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:` specifies the beginning of a list of parameters in an argument in a format string. These parameters describe exactly how to convert the corresponding value to a string (what trait to use, padding, alignment, precision, etc.).

For instance, in `{:?}`, `?` is a formatting type that instructs a `format!` family macro to delegate writing to the `Debug` trait.

You can see a description of the format string syntax in the [`std::fmt` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax).